# Text in kivy popup is outside the pop up

Tags: python, kivy

In a .kv file, I have

```py
<P>:
    ScrollView:
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: (self.width, None)
            id: table
            height: self.texture_size[1]
```

and in the corresponding .py file, I have

```py
class P(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, data1, data2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.table.text = str(data1[0] + data2[0])


def show_popup(data1, data2):
    show = P(data1, data2)
    popupWindow = Popup(title='Settings Window', content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    popupWindow.open()
```

However, the result is this:

[image]

How can I get the text to fall inside the popup window? If possible, I'd like to make the popup window much larger, and have a scrollable text in the window. I have tried messing around with `size_hint` and `pos_hint` as attirbutes of `<P>` to make the popup window bigger, and as attributes of `ScrollView` to move the text into the box, but this doesn't seem to be having any effect. (I used values between 0 and 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FloatLayout` does not position its children, you must do that. So there are three ways to correct your `P` class:

1. Add a `pos_hint` to position the `ScrollView`, probably like `pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}`.

Or,

2. Change the superclass of `P` from `FloatLayout` to `RelativeLayout`.

Or,

3. Just position the `ScrollView`, like `pos: root.pos`.

Comment: Thanks, `RelativeLayout` did the job. How would I go about making the pop up bigger? When I try to run this on mobile, the popup window is really small

Comment: ^ Never mind, I got it. I changed `popupWindow = Popup(title='Settings Window', content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))` to `popupWindow = Popup(title='Settings Window', content=show, size_hint=(0.8, 0.8))`